# capturing a sequence within a sequence

Tags: xquery

Say I have a sequence of items,

```
<items>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
</items>
```

and I want to capture all sequences of A- and B-items

```
<items>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <hit>
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
    </hit>
    <item>C</item>
</items>
```

Can this be done with XQuery? When iterating, the context item is singular.

I can get

```
<items>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <hit-start><item>A</item></hit-start>
    <hit-end><item>B</item></hit-end>
    <item>C</item>
</items>
```

but that does not help, nor does

```
<items>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <hit-start/>
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
    <hit-end/>
    <item>C</item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "look around" using `preceding-sibling` and `following sibling`.

```
<items>{
  for $item in $xml/items/item
  return
    if ($item = "A" and $item/following-sibling::item[1] = "B")
    then (
      <hit-start/>,
      <item>A</item>,
      <item>B</item>,
      <hit-end/>
    )
    else
      $item[not(preceding-sibling::item[1] = "A")]
}</items>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jens Erat, 
    `<items>{
      for $item in $items/item
      return
        if ($item = "A" and $item/following-sibling::item[1] = "B")
        then (
          <hit>
          <item>A</item>
          <item>B</item>
          </hit>
        )
        else
          $item[not(preceding-sibling::item[1] = "A")]
    }</items>`
is closer to what I want.

Comment: Overlooked the difference in the output. If this is what you're looking for, you can also omit the parentheses around `<hit>...</hit>`.